# Need to render textures uploaded by user in input files with Canvas renderer three.js

Tags: three.js, textures, webgl

I've loaded a Blender model using the `three.js` library and want to allow the users to change the texture of some faces through an input field in a form. I don't have any problem when I use the `WebGLRenderer`, and it works fine in Chrome, but it doesn't work with the canvas renderer when the texture coming from the input is in `data:image...` format. Seems if I load a full path image from the server it works fine. Does anybody know if there's a way to load textures this way and render them with the `canvasrenderer`?

Thank you.

I add here the code after I set the camera, lights and detect it the browswer detects webgl or not to use the WebGLRenderer or the CanvasRenderer.

First I load the model from blender:

```
 var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load('assets/models/mimaquina9.js', function (geometry, mat) {

        //I set the overdraw property to 1 for each material like i show here for 16    
        mat[16].overdraw = 1;          

        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(mat) );

        mesh.scale.x = 5;
        mesh.scale.y = 5;
        mesh.scale.z = 5;

        scene.add(mesh);

    }, 'assets/images');

        render();

    //To render, I try to make an animation in case WebGL is available and just render one frame in case of using the canvas renderer.
    function render() {

        if(webgl){

            if (mesh) {
                mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;
            }
            // render using requestAnimationFrame
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            webGLRenderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
        else if(canvas){

            camera.position.x = 30;
            camera.position.y = 20;
            camera.position.z = 40;
            camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 10, 0));

            setTimeout(function (){

                //something you want delayed
                webGLRenderer.render(scene, camera);
            }, 1000);

        }

    }


   $('#datafile').change(function(e)
   {
       e.preventDefault();
       var f = e.target.files[0];

       if(f && window.FileReader)
       {

           var reader = new FileReader();

           reader.onload = function(evt) {
                console.log(evt);

                        mesh.material.materials[16].map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(evt.target.result);

                            if(canvas && !webgl){
//I read that might be a problem of using Lambert materials, so I tried this commented line without success
                                //mesh.material.materials[16] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(evt.target.result)});
//If I uncomment the next line, it displays the texture fine when rendering after.    
                                //mesh.material.materials[16].map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("assets/images/foto.jpg");

                                render();

                            }

           }
           reader.readAsDataURL(f);


       }
   });
```

Thanks once more.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Hi @mrdoob, thanks for showing interest. I've edited the post adding the code and I hope you can help me, cause this is driving me really crazy ). Maybe it's something with paths, cause when the texture is changed from the input field, and it's in data:image format, it's the same effect as when it can't find the file if the texture is hosted in the server, which is, not showing those faces with the texture. But I'm just starting with this and really need some master help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`evt.target.result` is a `DataURL` so you should assign that to a `image.src`. Something like this should work:

```
var image = document.createElement( 'img' );
image.src = evt.target.result;

mesh.material.materials[16].map = new THREE.Texture( image );
```

Comment: Yes, I was just about to write a comment saying that I finally could do it that way as I just saw in an answer you gave to the question "How to load texture in jsfiddle". Thank you very much. I'd like to understand anyway why it worked without that assignment to image.src when using the WebGLRenderer. Muchísimas gracias.